# Damping factor formula

Tags: impedance, damping

I thought I understand damping factor, but apparently I was wrong.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping_factor

The article on wikipedia makes sense, but it doesn't explain why higher impedance of the speakers increases damping. It only says why low output impedance results in increased damping (less impedance - more current, that makes sense).

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the equation DF=Zload/Zsource. With a constant Zsource, an increased Zload results in an increased DF.

If you read the article carefully, the low output impedance referred to is actually the output impedance of the amplifier, which in this equation is Zsource. So, if you have a low Zsource, this would lead to a higher DF value.